# Movie about a boy that becomes small and befriends insects

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I think it's an older movie where a small boy becomes small and he befriends some creatures, and there's this spider woman who becomes his friend. He asks someone not to kill them.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I'm willing to bet you can remember a heck of a lot more. What did the boy look like? Was the film in colour? Was the film animated? Was the film in English? Where did you watch it? When did you watch it? Was the film aimed at adults or kids? Was there a secondary character? What was the boy's name? What was the spider-woman's name?

Comment: Thank you for asking more about it. But I got the answer and Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not "horror" (as per the tag), but this matches the 1996 film version of *James and the Giant Peach* (based on my favorite Roald Dahl novel).  The beginning, where James Henry Trotter is normal sized, is live action, but after he enters the oversized peach, the movie is done with stop-motion animation.  He befriends a group of giant invertebrates traveling on a peach, including a female spider.

Comment: Thank God. Thanks , Thats the movie :)

Comment: And I don't think he shrank so much as the peach, and the animals in and around it, got huge.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You're right!  That I had forgotten that bit means I should probably reread the whole book (with my kids).

Comment: The movie is actually Stop-Motion Animation, not CGI.